# PHP + jQuery .validate issue

Tags: php, jquery, validation

Ill try and make this as clear as possible. I have a contact form on a page and a remote PHP file "random.php" that generates 2 random numbers:

```
<?php
    $randomNum = rand(0,9);
    $randomNum2 = rand(0,9);
    echo $randomNum . ' + ' . $randomNum2;
    $randomNumTotal = $randomNum + $randomNum2;
?>
```

the parent page calls it as such:

```
$(function() {
    $.get( 'PHP/random.php', function ( data ) {
    $('#ResetNumbers").val(data);    
});
```

and has an input:

```
<input type="text" class="numbers" name="ResetNumbers" id="ResetNumbers" value=""    size="6" readonly>
```

No problems to this point, the php file output's the two random numbers and they are displayed on the page. **Here's the problem**:
I have a second text box where you have to add the two numbers to make it validate.

```
<input type="text" class="numbers" name="ResetMath"  id="ResetMath" size="6" maxlength="6" tabindex="27">
```

It never works. It always says its not added correctly. here is the relevant part of my validation rule which is in another remote file:

```
ResetMath: {
    required: true, 
    equal: <?php echo $randomNumTotal; ?>
}
```

Since this is in a remote file (don't want validation rules on the parent page) it doesn't seem to be getting the same numbers. How do I unscrew this mess?

Comment: does remote file where u write validation rule getting the value of `$randomNumTotal'..check using `console.log()`.. u must get that value on validation page

Comment: just stick console.log() where in the validation script?

Comment: Are you using the jQuery validation plugin; i.e. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate?

Comment: @Wayne yes thats what I'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ResetMath: {
    required: true, 
    equal: <?php echo $randomNumTotal; ?>
}
```

doesn't seem right. It should be:

```
ResetMath: {
    required: true, 
    equalTo: $('#ResetNumbers')
}
```

The API is [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/equalTo#other).

Comment: I don't believe that will get the SUM of the two numbers? It works when its all on one page, the validation function and the $randomNum + $randomNum2 function. It stores the sum in $randomNumTotal then checks against that

Comment: Oh I see. But if you want to use equalTo, the value has to stored in some field, which I assumed to be $('#ResetNumbers').

Comment: I need to store it somewhere but can't seem to get it to work

Comment: OK, so put it in some (new) hidden input field, and then set the value for equalTo to the jQuery expression that will select that field.

Comment: I couldn't store the number server side (not smart enough) so I used a custom validation rule client side to create a string of integers, remove the "+" and separate them, then combine and validate against that. your idea got me going. thx Wayne!

Answer (score 0):

How does your validation rule get its value for $randomNumTotal? is this in the same request as the one which returns the values for $randomNum and $randomNum2? If not, you have a problem - (different random numbers for each).

Comment: yes that is where my problem lies. I am going to echo the $randomNumTotal to the parent page as well and see if that helps. Possibly populate a hidden input with that value and compare against it?

Comment: Yeah, I've considered the hidden input for a similar project (this is for a CAPTCHA, I assume). The issue here is that it wouldn't be that hard for a robot to find the $randomNumTotal if it resides in the frontend code. But if you're not that worried about that, it'll work fine.